# Devise Stop Users Signing Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is there a way to temporarily disable signing up to allow a couple of users to sign up and test the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user model, there is something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Just remove :registerable from the list